# Count of values of all categorical variable using Python

Tags: python

I have a dataset with a large number of columns, how do I calculate the frequency of values of all categorical variables in Python? I don't want frequency for one or two specific columns rather I need the frequency of all variables `type="category"`.

Comment: Is there a special reason this is tagged r and sass (sas?)?

Comment: Thanks. However,  I am looking for a different output. Say , my dataset has 50 columns - 30 are categorical variables and 20 are numeric continuous variables. I want to get the frequency table for each of these 30 categorical variables. If I use df['column'].value_counts(), it gives the count of categories of the variable specified, when there are large no of variables, it is difficult to give the names of each variable in the code, rather I want something which can give me the same output for all categorical variables together.

Comment: I want an output of this kind below:                                                           
Gender        
M 200
F 300 Education 
Illiterate 50
School pass 150
College Graduate 200
Masters 50
PHD 50
Age 
<20 50
20-30 150
30-50 200
50-60 50
>60 50

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I know what you mean, but if you just want to keep a running count of frequencies, dictionaries are a great way to do this.

E.g. if we use the dummy data ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

```
category_counts = {}

for category in categories:
    try:
        category_counts[category] += 1
    except:
        category_counts[category] = 1
```

print(category_counts)

returns:

{'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}

EDIT: so if you want a count of the categories of each column the code only changes slightly to:

```
table = [['Male/Female','M','M','F','M',"F"],['Age','10-20','30-40','10-20','20-30','10-20']]

category_counts = {}

for column in table:
    category_counts[column[0]] = {}
    for data in column[1:]:
        try:
            category_counts[column[0]][data] += 1
        except:
            category_counts[column[0]][data] = 1

print(category_counts)
```

Which prints:

{'Male/Female': {'M': 3, 'F': 2}, 'Age': {'10-20': 3, '30-40': 1, '20-30': 1}}

But I'm unsure how you're currently storing your data

Answer (score 0):

Use [selected_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for selecting the columns with `type=category`, and use `sum()` method to calculate the frequencies:

```
df.select_dtypes(include='category').sum()
```

output:

```
col_cat1     9
col_cat2    21
```